# No module named '_tkinter' configured

Tags: python-3.7

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

I want to import turtle in Python 3.7

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "my.py", line 1, in 
>       from turtle import *   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/turtle.py", line 107, in 
>       import tkinter as TK   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/tkinter/**init**.py", line 36, in 
>       import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

Answer (score 1):

When building python from source, if the `Tk` development files are missing,
the build ends with

```
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_tkinter
```

The development files can be installed from the distribution packager.
for instance, in openSUSE Leap-15:

```
sudo zypper install tk-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

The IDE tells you that your python is not confingured for Tk (tkinter), which is your problem. While I am not certain on how to fix this becuase I never use turtle or Tk, I have a few ideas.

1. I am using python 3.7 and importing both turtle and Tk works just fine for me, so I definitely recommend updating to 3.7.
2. Look for Tk in your python module library and reinstall it.
3. Just find out how to confingure Tk with python 3.2 if updating doesn't work.

I hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

As @ederag said, I have installed Python3.7 and tkinter in opensuse.

```
sudo zypper refresh
sudo zypper update
sudo zypper in zlib-devel bzip2 libbz2-devel libffi-devel libopenssl-devel readline-devel sqlite3 sqlite3-devel xz xz-devel gcc tk-devel tcl-devel

cd ~/Downloads
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tar.xz
tar xf Python-3.7.3.tar.xz
cd Python-3.7.3
./configure
make
sudo make altinstall
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/lib-dynload /usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using linux go to terminal and type `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`

if you are using windows go to command prompt and type `cd C:/Program Files/Python/python37/Scripts` press enter then type `pip install tkinter`

hope it helped!